# disable one of validation rules Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have validation rules in my class which    extends FormRequest

```
return [
    'data.attributes.email' => ['required', 'email'],
    'data.attributes.phone' => ['required', 'string',],
];
```

if email is empty and phone is empty, i have 2 errors 'empty email' 'empty phone'. I want sutiation such as : if we have empty email - only error about email, if all rules of email is good, we use phone validation. Can i do this situation?

Answer (score 0):

How about the required_without rule

`required_without:foo,bar,...`

```
return [
    'data.attributes.email' => ['required_without:phone','email'],
    'data.attributes.phone' => ['required_without:email', 'string',],
];
```

Now you must have one or the other (I think :-) )